# iText7 Replace image loaded from HTML

Tags: html, pdf, itext, itext7

How do you load elements from HTML file and then replace the `src` property of the `<img />`, so that the image is dynamically replaced?

This questions comes from trying to have an HTML template of a pdf file and some data from database, and merging the two in a PDF file. Now It's pretty straightforward how you can replace text from paragraphs, headers, divs, table cells, etc.

```
divElement.GetChildren().Clear();
divElement.Add(new Paragraph(myText));
```

But how do you change the `src` property of the `<img />`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give one answer here, as I this is just something I stumbled upon after a lot of digging on the internet, without finding an answer for iText7 (just for iText5 and earlier).

you get to your image element (iText.Layout.Element.Image), we'll call it just `image` and then you:

```
// get image bytes, for example I do it by downloading an image from the URL
byte[] imageBytes;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(myImageUrl);
}

// convert it to stream
var pdfStream = ((PdfStream)image.GetXObject().GetPdfObject());

// put those bytes to good use
pdfStream.GetOutputStream().Reset();
pdfStream.GetOutputStream().WriteBytes(imageBytes);
```

Note that for this to work

1. `<img />` has to have a populated and valid `src` property. That means that the image will not be shown at all if when you open the HTML template you don't see an image. If you see it though, then it will be replaced using the code above.
2. `<img />` has to have a CSS class that describes its `width` and `height`. If not, image will have 0 width and 0 height and thus not be shown.

I couldn't find a simple example like this on the internet, so I'm posting a solution here. Hope it helps someone.